# Python - Test if string is before another string

Tags: python, string

File contents:

```
abc 
Swan
abc2
Swan
abc3
```

... How would test to see if "Swan" exists, but only before "abc2" (in Python)

(First post, so pls excuse a bit of ignorance

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Reading the file? Looping over the lines? Checking if a line has a certain value? Stop looping if you find a certain value? Please share your code and explain what problem you're having exactly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you write code that looks at the file a line at a time? Did you try checking whether the current line is "Swan", and then checking whether the next line is "abc2"? What specifically did you find difficult about it?

Answer (score 1):

One can use this:

```
txt = '''
abc 
Swan
abc2
Swan
abc3
'''

import re

if re.search(r'Swan\nabc2', txt, re.M):
    print('True')
```

This will look if there is somewhere in the text `Swan` and somewhere (not direct) behind it there should be abc2.

If you are looking per line one can loop over the lines:

```
lst_txt = txt.split('\n')
for line, lineafter in zip(lst_txt[:-1], lst_txt[1:]):
    if line == 'Swan' and lineafter == 'abc2':
        print('True')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have the data from the file as a string, you can split it into lines, if its in lines, then just convert it to a list of all lines. You can then use list.index() to find what line the value appears on and compare it to other values like so:

```
testStr = """abc 
Swan
abc2
Swan
abc3"""

lines = testStr.splitlines()

print(lines.index('Swan'))
print(lines.index('abc2'))
if lines.index('Swan') < lines.index('abc2'):
    print('Swan comes before abc2')
```

Which outputs:

```
1
2
Swan comes before abc2
```

Answer (score 0):

if file is txt file, this can be the way.
ex) filename : content.txt

```
with open('content.txt', 'r') as f:
    r = f.readlines()
    for i, val in enumerate(r):
        word = val.replace('\n', '')
        if val == 'Swan':
            print('Position of Swan :', i)
        elif val == 'abc2':
            print('Position of abc2 :', i)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

`x_before_y` iterates through a iterable (e.g. a list) and returns `True` as soon as it finds a string `x` that occurs before the string `y`.

```
def x_before_y(x, y, iterable):
    for i, el in enumerate(iterable):
        if el == y and iterable[i-1] == x:
            return True
    return False

lines = ["x", "Swan", "abc2", "x", "Swan"]
x_before_y("Swan", "abc2", lines) #  True
x_before_y("abc2", "Swan", lines) #  False
```